# React.js div scrollIntoView not smooth

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript

I have a display component that essentially just displays a list of cards. I have another component that fetches a card and adds it to a `cards` state that the Display component has access to to map and render the cards out. Upon adding a card to `cards`, I have an empty div at the bottom of the display that I want to scroll into view so users can automatically see the new card without having to scroll. I'm using a ref to get the div reference and using the `scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' })` method but it is not smoothly scrolling. I've also tried adding `html { scroll-behavior: smooth }` as CSS but that doesn't fix the issue either.

**Display.tsx**

```
const Display: React.FC = () => {
  const bottomDivRef = useRef<null | HTMLDivElement>(null)

  // currentSessionThreads is a list of ID associated with a card's information. State is stored using Redux
  const currentSessionThreads = useSelector((store: IRootState) => {
    const currentSession = store.ideator.value.currentSession
    if (currentSession === null) {
      return
    }
    return store.ideator.value.sessionsMap[currentSession].threads
  })
  const threadsMap = useSelector(
    (store: IRootState) => store.ideator.value.threadsMap
  )
  const ideasMap = useSelector(
    (store: IRootState) => store.ideator.value.ideasMap
  )

  // Everytime a new ID is added to currentSessionThreads, scroll the newest card into view.
  useEffect(() => {
    bottomDivRef.current?.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' })
  }, [currentSessionThreads])

  return (
    <Box flex='1'>
      <VStack w='100%'>
        {currentSessionThreads?.map((threadID, index) => {
          return (
            <IdeaCard
              idea={ideasMap[threadsMap[threadID].idea]}
              ideaNumber={index + 1}
              key={index}
            />
          )
        })}
      </VStack>

      <Box w='100%' h='8rem' ref={bottomDivRef} />
    </Box>
  )
}
```

When I add a new card via another component that updates the redux store containing the currentSessionThreads, it doesn't scroll the new content smoothly. It just jumps to it. I'm not sure why this isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

Some workaround that I suggest is:

1. Check the css from Developer Tools (F12) if there's any `scroll-behavior` that conflicted with your code.
2. You can try adding `important` tag in your css to make sure it's applicable.
3. Try in another browser if it's still not working.

Alternative method that you can try is adding `scroll-behavior: smooth` in html tag via Developer Tools. Then go to `console` and write `window.scrollTo(0,0)` to check if it is smooth or not. If smooth then maybe something is wrong in your react code.

Hope that might helps

Answer (score 0):

Ran all the tests regarding smooth scrolling. Turns out, it was because I disabled Animation effects in the Visual effects settings in Windows 11. Turned it back on and see it working now.